# git alias fatal: ambiguous argument '%ad': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: windows, git, alias

Прохожу курс https://githowto.com/ru/aliases. Возникла проблема, при вводе `git log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short` возникает ошибка

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '%ad': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Пробовал менять кавычки `git log --pretty='format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\"' --graph --date=short`, но получал тоже самое. Как исправить?

Comment: зачем тут обратные слэши? вам же просто строку надо передать: `$ git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short` // p.s. к программе git это, конечно, не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо, помогло. Не я придумал эти обратные слеши, они были в примере задания.

Comment: в примере, подозреваю, приводилась команда, создающая псевдоним. и в этой команде, вероятно, приведённая вами строка была заключена в кавычки и выступала лишь частью команды.